# send result of a query to a servlet in pages of 10 item java

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I want to do this: when I receive a get request i should show my list of Customer that i have in my db. I have 300 customer, how i can do if i want to show them in pages of 10 item? I have think that i can receive from the get request the number of the page and show the first 10 if page is 1 the customers from 11 to 20 is 2 but i don't know how to do that,can someone help me?
This is my doGet method

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String id = req.getParameter("idCustomer");
    Gson g = new Gson();
    try {
        ManageCustomer manageCustomer = new ManageCustomer();
        System.out.println("********** \n\nID="+ id + " \n\n*****************");
        if (id != null)) { 
            Customer customer = manageCustomer.findCustomerById(id);
            if (customer == null)  
                resp.setStatus(404);
            if (customer != null) { 
               //only one customer
                resp.getOutputStream().println(g.toJson(customer));
                resp.setStatus(200);
            }
        } else {
//here i have all the customer in a list
            List<Customer> customers = manageCustomer.findAllCustomers();
            if (customers != null) { 
                resp.getOutputStream().println(g.toJson(customers));
                resp.setStatus(200);
            } else // customer not found
                resp.setStatus(404);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        resp.setStatus(500);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps..

**EDIT :** size limit check added..

```
int pageNum = 
    req.getParameter("pageNum") == null || req.getParameter("pageNum").equals("") ?
        0 : Integer.parseint(req.getParameter("pageNum"));
(pageNum + 1) * 10 <= customers.size()? 
    customers = customers.subList(pageNum * 10, (pageNum + 1) * 10)
    : customers = customers.subList(pageNum * 10, customers.size());
```

Comment: this helps much but there is a problem, if i want to show customers from 300 to 310 and i have only 309 customers goes on arrayindexoutofbound and i can't show the 9 customer between that range –

Comment: ok but the second sublist not work, you haven't the second index

Comment: i have always indexOutOfBounds...i don't know how to do! :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage the resultset Hibernate fetches using in your queries:

```
query.setFirstResult(...);
query.setMaxResults(PAGE_SIZE); //should be 10 in your case
```

To get the first result you can do something like the following:

```
protected int getFirstElement(PaginationDTO dto) {
    if(dto.getPage() <= 1){
         return 0; //allows user to send page = 1, instead of being 0 based
    }

    return (dto.getPage() - 1) * PAGE_SIZE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ManageCustomer create a new method

```
List<Customer> findAllCustomer(int currentPage,int pageSize ){
    Query selectQuery = session.createQuery("QUERY_FOR_FETCHING_ALL_CUSTOMER");
    selectQuery.setFirstResult((currentPage- 1) * pageSize);
    selectQuery.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    List<Customer> customers = selectQuery.list();
    return customers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take two parameters `limit` and `offset` in your `GET` request,here `limit` is 10.
Then in your db query you can pass these parameters value to make your query 
and since you're using hibernate you can use something like this,

```
// SQL: SELECT colum_name FROM table LIMIT offset, limit;

Query query = session.createQuery("FROM table");
query.setFirstResult(start);
query.setMaxResults(maxRows);
```

The `resultset` object even tells you whether there are anymore results or not, so you can use that to `enable/disable` the a `next` button.
If there are more results send new numbers to hibernate `offset+limit` and `limit`